# Auto Increment in wikitable using python

Tags: python, mediawiki, wikipedia

I have mediawiki user statistics in wikitable format, which have been generated by sql query. 
Now I would like to replace all `#` exist in first column and in every row to auto increment numbers i.e 1,2,3,4 starting from first row using python script.

Any idea how to accomplish this task?

Data in wikitable format:

```
matter = """{| class="wikitable"
!number!!user_id!!user_name!!byte_count!!edit_count
|-
|#||19745||[[user:abc|abc]]||37294210.0||83282
|-
|#||21818||[[user:abc|abc]]||3420248.0||121794
|-
|#||21548||[[user:abc|abc]]||2515274.0||32799
|}"""

with open("wikit.txt", 'w') as f:
    f.write(matter)

with open('wikit.txt', 'r') as f:
    m = f.read()

print(m)
```

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tested but it should work for you

```
   with open('wikit.txt', 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    newlines =[]
    line_num=1
    for line in lines:
        newlines.append(line.replace("#",str(line_num)))
        if "#" in line:
           line_num+=1

   newlines_str='\n'.join(line for line in newlines)

    with open("wikit.txt", 'w') as f:
        f.write(newlines_str)
```

Comment: Now: `TypeError: write() argument must be str, not list`

Comment: Updated again .